# How to split revenue for column value after applying STUFF function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this grid1
I used STUFF function to create grid2
I need the grid3 result when I apply a filter on any of the 2 stuffed columns.

[image]

Comment: you already SUM()med the value for Revenue, how would you get the original value from that in Grid 2. you will have to use Grid 1 for that.

Comment: Seems like a poor db design to me. Why you need Grid2? as long as you can get the sum easily by a simply query from Grid1?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar, I want to use grid2 as a default view in my asp.net web page and upon applying a filter on any of the three columns (UID or Year Or Geo) it should return me grid3.

Comment: Use grid 2 to display, use grid 1 to select from the data when filter is used then display as grid 3.

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar, Would it be possible to return either of the three column values in both Year & Geo column from Grid2 and only a single row? Since this would be a default grid view in asp.net

Comment: as i've said, you already SUM()med the value for revenue. if you use grid 2, how would you split it up and come up with the original value from grid 1?

Comment: you want to get `grid3` from `grid2` or `grid1`?

Answer (score 2):

The following is capable of producing the results of both Grid_2 and Grid_3, depending on filter selection.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    [UID] INT NOT NULL,
    [Year] INT NOT NULL,
    Geo CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    Revenue MONEY NOT NULL 
    );

INSERT #TestData (UID, Year, Geo, Revenue) VALUES 
    (1234556, 2015, 'US', 1500),
    (1234556, 2016, 'IN', 1800),
    (1234556, 2017, 'FR', 1900);

-- SELECT * FROM #TestData td;

--=======================================================

DECLARE 
    @Year INT = NULL,
    @Geo CHAR(2) = NULL;

SELECT 
    td1.[UID],
    [Year] = MAX(STUFF(cy.ConcatYear, 1, 1, '')),
    Geo = MAX(STUFF(cg.ConcatGeo, 1, 1, '')),
    Revenue = SUM(td1.Revenue)
FROM
    #TestData td1
    CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT 
                CONCAT(',', td2.[Year])
            FROM
                #TestData td2
            WHERE 
                td1.[UID] = td2.[UID]
                AND (td2.[Year] = @Year OR @Year IS NULL)
                AND (td2.Geo = @Geo OR @Geo IS NULL)
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ) cy (ConcatYear)
    CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT 
                CONCAT(',', td3.Geo)
            FROM
                #TestData td3
            WHERE 
                td1.[UID] = td3.[UID]
                AND (td3.[Year] = @Year OR @Year IS NULL)
                AND (td3.Geo = @Geo OR @Geo IS NULL)
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ) cg (ConcatGeo)
WHERE 
    (td1.[Year] = @Year OR @Year IS NULL)
    AND (td1.Geo = @Geo OR @Geo IS NULL)
GROUP BY
    td1.[UID]
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

> @Year INT = NULL, @Geo CHAR(2) = NULL; -- RESULTS...

```
UID         Year            Geo        Revenue
----------- --------------- ---------- ---------------------
1234556     2015,2016,2017  US,IN,FR   5200.00
```

> @Year INT = 2015, @Geo CHAR(2) = NULL; -- RESULTS...

```
UID         Year            Geo        Revenue
----------- --------------- ---------- ---------------------
1234556     2015            US         1500.00
```

Comment: any particular reason for the `option (recompile)` ?

Comment: @squirrel it's because of two sets of optional parameters. The option(recompile) allows the possibly of doing an index seek when one or both parameters is not null.